# glBufferData does not delete existing data store

Tags: opengl

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBufferData.xhtml) states

> glBufferData creates a new data store for the buffer object currently
>   bound to target. Any pre-existing data store is deleted. The new data
>   store is created with the specified size in bytes and usage.

So I code

```
    // allocate storage in GPU and copy data
    glBufferData(
      GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
      myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),
      myData.Vertex(),
      GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    ...
    glDrawArrays(
      GL_TRIANGLES,
      0,
      myData.VertexCount() );
```

which is executed every time I need to refresh the scene.

From time to time the number of vertices changes greatly.  When the number of vertices drops, the old data appears to be still present and a garbled rendering of the old data appears.

I can workaround this problem by creating the buffer index at the start of each refresh, then deleting it afterwards

```
    // construct buffer index
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

   ...

   glDeleteBuffers(1,&vertexbuffer);
```

This is fine for the moment, but I would like to optmize things later, including reusing some of the vertices in the buffer without needing to make a fresh copy on each refresh.

The problem does not show up on all my machines.  It looks like the machines with better graphics cards do not have the problem

For reference, here is the entire render code:

```
    void Render()
    {
        // Background color
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

        glUseProgram( myShaderID );

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(myMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

        // enable vertices attribute buffer
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // make current
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

        // allocate storage in GPU and copy data
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),
                     myData.Vertex(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

        // let shaders access buffer
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),
                     myData.Color(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myData.VertexCount() );

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glFlush();
        myCanvas->SwapBuffers();
}
```

And here is the final, fixed production code.  VertexCount() now returns actual count of vertices, not just the number of floats in the vertex vector.

```
/** Update GL display */
void Render()
{
    // Background color
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUseProgram( myShaderID );

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(
        myMatrixID,
        1,
        GL_FALSE,
        myCamera.ModelViewProjection() );

    // enable vertices attribute buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // make current
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertexBufferID);

    // allocate storage in GPU and copy data
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        3 * myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),
        myData.Vertex(),
        GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    // let shaders access buffer
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myColorBufferID);
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        3 * myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),
        myData.Color(),
        GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myData.VertexCount() );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glFlush();
    myCanvas->SwapBuffers();

}
```

Comment: "pre-existing data store is deleted" not "data store**d**" How are you able to render old data? Don't you update it when you refresh? Do you use a different *count* on glDrawXXX not matching the one used at glBufferData? How would you hope to reuse data you have declared as deleted before? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Consider a bufferID (i.e. a "data store") like a C++ pointer. You can delete the pointer without clearing the data pointed to. Only mark the memory as free again.

Comment: glBufferData is a buffer copy, not a buffer map -- the storage should be considered new-to-you and uninitialized. If you are seeing old data on render, you are either uploading old data, or triggering undefined behavior somehow (e.g. rendering too many vertices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is just not correct. You set up the vertex attrib pointer to read 3 `GLfloat`s per vertex, and use `myData.VertexCount()` as the number of vertices in the draw call, but you upload only `myData.VertexCount()*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` bytes to the VBO. As a result, you will read way past the end of the buffer, and results are just undefined behavior.

.

Comment: I think I see.  I need to write  <pre>glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myData.VertexCount() / 3 );</pre>

Comment: You can do that, but I would recommend calling `VertexCount` something else then, since it's not what the name suggests.

Comment: That was quick fix to test my understanding of your answer.  In production code, I left the glDrawArrays call unchanged and wrote and tripled the byte count passed to glBufferData

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that when you call `glBufferData` the GL driver gives you a position in its memory which likely is the same as the previous position. You think you can update *part of the whole* thing with `glBufferData`, but that's not true. The rest may coincide with old data or may not.

I think you'd better use `glBufferSubData` instead of `glBufferData` to update new data (or part of it) without deleting and recreating a data store.

You need deleting and recreating when newSize > oldSize.

Comment: This explanation makes sense as far as it goes.  It does not explain why the old data is being drawn.  I call glDrawArrays with the correct, reduced, vertex count but it goes ahead and renders vertices way past that count.

Comment: Do you call `glBindBuffer` again before `glBufferData`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'again'.  I do call call glBindBuffer just before glBufferData